# Parallelize for adding up Counters in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

There is a list of dictionaries to be added up.

```
list_of_dictionaries = [{"a":1,"b":2,...},{"a":2,"b":2,...},...]
combined_dictionary = {}

for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
   combined_dictionary = Counter(combined_dictionary) + Counter(dictionary)

print(combined_dictionary)
```

I want to do it with multiple cores because `list_of_dictionaries` is very large.

Can anyone help me with it?

I have read 30+ solutions online related to multiprocessing (including using shared dictionaries in multiprocessing.pool.process) but I haven't noticed any that could solve my problem. I hope someone will give a more relevant link or some code for this task.

Thanks!

Jerry

Comment: how big is the dictionary? number of items? if it's so large that this is slow then i'm surprised memory isn't the issue. BTW combined_dictionary is overwrriten every loop iteration

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'd call it replaced by a new dictionary/counter, although that's likely what you meant. `combined_dictionary.update(dictionary)` may already be somewhat more efficient - even though it's not multithreaded - as it doesn't recreate new dictionaries every time, but just increases existing or adds new keys, as appropriate. It requires you to initialize it like this: `combined_dictionary = Counter()` instead of `= {}`

Comment: There are 81 million dictionaries in the list. They each represent one mutation in the 1000 genomes vcfs.

Comment: i'm sure there's a better way of doing this, some bioinformatics package that parses vcfs

Comment: blubberdiblub, thanks, it is much faster.

Comment: Chris, yes there are many. But for the task of counting different kinds for variants, I have not found any package to do that. Using my custom python script with `multiprocessing.Pool` and run on a 32-core server (though old), the speed for converting each line to a processed dictionary counting statistics required is fairly quick.

Comment: I still think it could possibly be improved performance-wise with subdividing (classical divide-and-conquer) and parallelizing it, as each subdivision can be processed independently from the others. You just have to make sure not to create actual copies of the data, just refer to it (via slices or indices or whatever). And it will create new objects holding the sums at each level in contrast to the plain-and-simple single-threaded `.update()`, so it's not clear whether it'll really be faster and will need to be attempted and measured.

Comment: @blubberdiblub The above solution is satisfactory because it took 40 minutes to complete, much faster than the estimated 40 hours in my original script. Increasing complexity could increase mistakes for an inexperienced coder like me so I don't want to use it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about adding up such dictionaries as efficiently as possible, it doesn't get better than MapReduce.

MapReduce is famous for being used by Google to add up and process huge amounts of data in a manner similar to what you described. It scales the work up seamlessly to multiple cores and can be used to scale the work up across a swarm of computers in a network.

---

Resources:

- [Wikipedia: MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)
- [Python MapReduce tutorial](https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/11/17/python-map-reduce-on-hadoop-a-beginners-tutorial.html)

Comment: Good idea. I shall try it when I need a bigger computation. UK biobank just released exome data for 50k individuals.

Comment: @JohnSmith I suggest you ask this on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ . You can't expect people here on Stack Overflow to know what exome data and UK biobank is